# Adding nuget package for DeveloperForce.Force in Asp.net Core throw error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, salesforce, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I am trying add to add Force package in my asp.net core application but it is throwing an error.

**Package DeveloperForce.Force 1.3.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0**

I  have looked on the web Force package for core framework But i couldnot find. Is there a way to bypass this error.

Comment: The issue is pretty clear: you are targetting .NET Core and the package is built for the full .NET Framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I got it.

In my project.json file. I updated the frameworks.

```
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8",
        "net45"
      ],
      "dependencies": {
      }
    }
```

I added the net45 and than added the nuget package it works now. It only shown a warning on the salesforce class
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to remove .NET Core support from the project(s) consuming that package. There's no other way without the owners of `DeveloperForce.Force` upgrading their packages.